# IR2104S package differs from an older one, can it be a fake one or is it alright?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, markings

The left one is from an older order, and I have already used this (I mean another one that looks the same) and it works fine.

The right one is from a new order, and it has some differences, namely:

- Different font
- In the IR logo, the ratio of the diode symbol seems a bit off
- The pins are narrower
- The 1st pin marking is a small "hole", instead of a marking

I haven't tested it yet.

[image: Front side]

---

[image: Markings according to the datasheet]

According to the datasheet, the assembly site code is different (C vs. H). Can this be the only reason for the differences?

The date code is 9 on the left one and 2 on the right one. I assume they correspond to 2019 and 2012, is it possible?

Does the Lot Code tell anything useful?

---

Their back side is also different:

[image: Back side]

What do you think?

Comment: Your local IR FAE or the distributor you used may be able to trace the lot code for you.

Comment: The cost of sourcing the part from a legit source is faster and cheaper than trying to determine the provenance. If the chip is a fake and it blows up your expensive mosfets etc, then any perceived value has just flown out the window.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I decided to try it to be sure, with a current limited power supply in case something goes wrong.Well, it seems to be defective. I won't investigate it further, because I'm afraid it would kill something else on the panel, too. I will ask the distributor.

Comment: When the Semiconductor makers started to ship Pb (lead) free parts a few changed the packages to accommodate there newer assembly equipment. If your dealer cannot trace it and you really want to know you can have the unit decapped and look at the logo on the die. Because of the danger of the chemicals I suggest you send it out.